# Statistics and probability

Tags: probability

How can I  choose which to use permutation or combination to solve a given statistical problem in maths.
Eg. In how many ways can the letters of word: "ARRANGE" be arranged? How many of these arrangements are there in which
a) the two R's together
b)the two R's and two A's come together

Comment: If you do a search on this website for "ARRANGE" you'll find lots of questions like this

Comment: @MartinHansen thankyou martin the answer is correct ,but my basic question is if there is a way to decide methods from permutation and combination when solving such problems just by looking

Comment: I've added an explanation - hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is $\frac {7!} {2! \cdot 2!} = 1260$ and the answer to $(a)$ is $\frac {6!} {2!} = 360$ and answer to $(b)$ is $5! = 120.$

Comment: Although correct, it helps to explain why each number was chosen and the thought process on how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Part b) is easier so I'll do that first.

Imagine you have 5 cards on which is written
$$ aa : rr : n : g : e$$
You are going to place these cards is a line on a table,
There are 5 possible cards you could place first, then four second, three third, two fourth and then what ever card is left in your hand goes down last.
So that's, $$5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \ 1 = 5! = 120$$
With part a) you have 6 cards on which is written
$$ a : a : rr : n : g : e$$
So repeating the argument above there are 6! ways of placing the cards.
There is a catch however which is the two 'a' cards that look the same.
So you can't tell the difference between, for example,
$$n \implies a_1 \implies rr \implies g \implies a_2 \implies e$$
and
$$n \implies a_2 \implies rr \implies g \implies a_1 \implies e$$
so the 6! needs dividing by 2!, i.e. 2, giving an answer of 360

Hope that helps !